# Allow a limited amount of users to login using FB login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In our organization we have a website that stores all our clients data. until recently this was hidden behind a htaccess file. This setup was primitive and I'm in the process of making it better.

My idea is that I want to have an account for everyone in the organization but I don't want them to register with a new username and password and just let them login using their facebook account.

So I was wondering if it would be possible to use the facebook login button but only let a certain list of people login? And if possible maybe some guidelines on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could leave the app in test mode, and add all those people as developers/testers. Other than that, you would have to implement a check yourself, after the user has logged in.

Comment: So you are saying that I should let everybody login and just check on every page if they are in my whitelist?